# How to timeout a tail pipeline properly on shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, timeout

I am implementing `monitor_log` function which will tail the most recent line from running log and check required string with while loop, the timeout logic should be when the tail log running over 300 seconds, it must close the tail and while loop pipeline.

The big issue i found is for some server the running log **NOT** keep generating, which means `tail -n 1 -f "running.log"` will also **NOT** generate output for `while` loop to consume, hence the timeout checking logic `if [[ $(($SECONDS - start_timer)) -gt 300 ]]` will not hit properly.

*e.g* I set `300` seconds to timeout, but if `running.log` stopped generate new line before `300` seconds and no more new line in `30` minutes, `tail` will not generate new output in `30` minutes, hence timeout checking logic in `while` loop not hit in `30` minutes, so even after `300` seconds it keep tailing and not break out, and if no new line coming from `running.log` forever, the timeout checking logic will not hit forever.

```
function monitor_log() {
  if [[ -f "running.log" ]]; then
    # Timer start
    start_timer=$SECONDS
    # Tail the running log last line and keep check required string
    tail -n 1 -f "running.log" | while read tail_line
    do
      if [[ $(($SECONDS - start_timer)) -gt 300 ]]; then
        break;
      fi
      if [[ "$tail_line" == "required string" ]]; then
        capture_flag=1
      fi
      if [[ $capture_flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        break;
      fi
    done
  fi
}
```

Could you help to figure out the proper way to timeout the tail and while loop when `300` seconds ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options worth considering for inactivity timeout. Usually, option #1 works better.

**Option 1: Use timeout (`read -t timeout`).**

It will cap the the 'read' time. See information from bash man. The timeout will cause the read to fail, breaking the whlie loop.

In the code above, replace

```
tail -n 1 -f "running.log" | while read tail_line
```

with

```
 tail -n 1 -f "running.log" | while read -t 300 tail_line
```

**Option 2: TMOUT envvar**

It's possible to get same effect by setting TMOUT env var.

**From bash man - 'read' command:**

> -t timeout
>
> Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input (or a specified number of characters) is not
>   read within timeout seconds.  timeout may be a decimal number with  a 
>   fractional
>                        portion  following  the  decimal  point.  This option is only effective if read is reading input from a terminal,
>   pipe, or other special file; it has no effect when reading from
>   regular files.  If
>                        read times out, read saves any partial input read into the specified variable name.  If timeout is 0, read returns
>   immediately, without trying to read any data.  The exit status is 0 if
>   input  is
>                        available on the specified file descriptor, non-zero otherwise.  The exit status is greater than 128 if the
>   timeout is exceeded.

Comment: that's great suggestion, i have tried first option, the `-t` option in `read` command is really useful, only one thing want to mention, in my running, if `tail` before `while read loop`, looks like `while read loop` is in subscript, so not sure why `-t` not working, but i check other doc: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309453/bash-tail-f-with-while-read-and-pipe-hangs/309455, it give a solution to move `tail` after `while read loop`, then the additional `-t` on `read` command works for me, will post my testing result below, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Based on dash-o's answer I did test for option 1, the `-t` for `read` command works fine only when `while read loop` on main shell and `tail` in sub shell, in my question, the `tail` in main shell, and `while read loop` consume its output in subshell, in this condition, even setup `-t` for `read` command, script not stop when time used up. Refer to
[Monitoring a file until a string is found](https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found), [Bash tail -f with while-read and pipe hangs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309453/bash-tail-f-with-while-read-and-pipe-hangs/309455) and [How to [constantly] read the last line of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189663/how-to-constantly-read-the-last-line-of-a-file)

The working code based on dash-o's solution below:

```
function monitor_log() {
  if [[ -f "running.log" ]]; then
    # Tail the running log last line and keep check required string
    while read -t 300 tail_line
    do
      if [[ "$tail_line" == "required string" ]]; then
        capture_flag=1
      fi
      if [[ $capture_flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        break;
      fi
    done < <(tail -n 1 -f "running.log")
    # Silently kill the remained tail process
    tail_pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'tail' | cut -d' ' -f5)
    kill -13 $tail_pid
  fi
}
```

But as test, this function after timeout auto terminate will left `tail` process alive, we can observe `PID` by check `ps -ef` on console, need to `kill tail_PID` separately.

Also test another solution: not change `tail` and `while read loop` position, so `tail` still on main shell and `while read loop` keep in sub shell after `|` pipeline, the only change is adding GNU's `timeout` command before `tail` command, it works perfect and no `tail` process left after timeout auto terminate:

```
function monitor_log() {
  if [[ -f "running.log" ]]; then
    # Tail the running log last line and keep check required string
    timeout 300 tail -n 1 -f "running.log" | while read tail_line
    do
      if [[ "$tail_line" == "required string" ]]; then
        capture_flag=1
      fi
      if [[ $capture_flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        break;
      fi
    done
  fi
}
```

Comment: note ‘while -t 300 read ...’ should be ‘while read -t 300 ...’