# How to get correct tail PID under multiple process in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, fork

I am implementing `monitor_log` function which will tail the most recent line from running log and check required string with while loop, the timeout logic should be when the tail log running over 300 seconds, it must close the tail and while loop pipeline. Refer to [How to timeout a tail pipeline properly on shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417728/how-to-timeout-a-tail-pipeline-properly-on-shell), as mentioned even `monitor_log` function finished, **it will left `tail` process on background**, so I have to manually kill it in case of hundreds times calling `monitor_log` will left hundreds of `tail` process.

The function `monitor_log` below kill correct `tail` PID **only under single process situation**, because `tail_pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'tail' | cut -d' ' -f5)` will return the correct `tail` PID which on the only process. When comes to multiple process situation(process fork), for example, multiple calls of `monitor_log` function to parallel tail log, there will be multiple `tail` process running, `tail_pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'tail' | cut -d' ' -f5)` not able to return exactly `tail` PID which belong to current fork.

So is that possible to **NOT** left `tail` process when `monitor_log` function finished ? OR if left `tail` process, is there a proper way to find its **correct** PID (not the `tail` PID from other thread) and kill it under multiple process situation ?

```
function monitor_log() {
  if [[ -f "running.log" ]]; then
    # Tail the running log last line and keep check required string
    while read -t 300 tail_line
    do
      if [[ "$tail_line" == "required string" ]]; then
        capture_flag=1
      fi
      if [[ $capture_flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        break;
      fi
    done < <(tail -n 1 -f "running.log")
    # Not get correct tail PID under multiple process
    tail_pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'tail' | cut -d' ' -f5)
    kill -13 $tail_pid
  fi
}
```

Comment: Your question is misleading - there is no "multithreading" within a bash script. Shell scripts are about process forking. Ofc those can run in parallel (multiprocessing != multithreading)

Comment: Ok, that's a good suggest, "multiplethreading" is the wrong term used for describe the case here since i am a bit new to embedded mechanism of script, let me update to "process fork"

Comment: Maybe refer to it as "running multiple invocations in parallel in the background" - then its automatically clear, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, jerch, still check on it, thanks for advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below code:

```
function monitor_log() {
  if [[ -f "running.log" ]]; then
    # Tail the running log last line and keep check required string
    while read -t 300 tail_line
    do
      if [[ "$tail_line" == "required string" ]]; then
        capture_flag=1
      fi
      if [[ $capture_flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        break;
      fi
    done < <(tail -n 1 -f "running.log")

     tailpid=$!

     kill $tailpid
  fi
}
```

>
$!   Gives the Process ID (PID) of last job run in background

Update: This would kill the subshell which triggers the tail as suggested in comment

Another way might be add timeout to the tail command as below:

```
timeout 300s tail -n 1 -f "running.log"
```

Comment: Thanks Alok, i have tried this, but still not sure if this will get correct PID, as i know `tail` after `while read loop` called as `sub shell`, as I observe the `tailpid` getting by `$!` here not exactly match the PID getting by `ps -ef | grep 'tail'` even under single call, but i need more test to confirm this.

Comment: It returns the PID of the subshell (tail runs within that subshell).

Comment: Yeah, jerch, agree on "It returns the PID of the subshell (tail runs within that subshell)", as test, like Alok mentioned, if query most recent PID with `$!`, it will return subshell's PID, not exactly the `tail` command PID(5695), but its the parent PID (5694, PPID) for `tail`. I am working on a way to use this PPID(5694) to get its child process `tail`(5695), e.g:  

$ ps -ef
     UID     PID    PPID    TTY        STIME      COMMAND
      me    5695    5694    pty0      16:18:53     /usr/bin/tail
      me    5694          1    pty0      16:18:53     /usr/bin/bash

Comment: Hi, Alok, as test and also confirmed by jerch, also based on your comments, update to accept as correct solution

Comment: In that case you may try adding a timeout to the tail itself like ( timeout 300s tail -n 1 -f "running.log")

Comment: Yeah, i tried also and post in my related topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417728/how-to-timeout-a-tail-pipeline-properly-on-shell, the reason i have to use `while read loop + tail` pattern instead of `tail + while read loop` pattern since a problem similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166546/bash-cannot-break-out-of-piped-while-read-loop-process-substitution-works, the wanted flag on the last line or second last line of running log and will not generate new line, `tail` on main process even capture the flag will not get new trigger event, only `while` ahead works

Comment: I mean `tail` on main process even capture the flag will not get new trigger event to break out before timeout, e.g when flag captured, it only take 100 seconds, and you set up as 300 seconds to timeout, if `tail` on main shell with `timeout` setup, but flag on your last or 2nd last line, `tail` captured the flag well but not able to get new coming line to hit the logic to break out `while` loop, only `while read loop` on main shell and `tail` on sub shell will break out. One more thing, to kill the `tail` PID, only kill `subshell` PID not enough, need `subshell` as PPID to get `tail` PID